# return function value javascript recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

[image]

Using recursion return value of this function. Only one parameter is allowed in function. Also global variables outside of function are not allowed.

Comment: have u tried anything?

Comment: `function test(n,i){
  if(n>0){
    return ((n/(1+i))+test(n-1,i+1));
  }else{return 0;}
}`

this works. buit i have to do it with only one parameter

Answer (score 0):

using your code with two parameters, assuming it's correct, cheat like this

```
function f(x) {
    function inner(n, i) { 
        if (n>0) { 
            return (( n / (1 + i)) + inner(n-1, i+1) ); 
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        } 
    }
    return inner(x);
}
```

or you can of course do this

```
function test(o) {
    if (typeof o == 'number') {
        o = { i: 0, n: o };
    }
    if (o.n > 0) {
        return ((o.n / (1 + o.i)) + test({ n: o.n - 1, i: o.i + 1 }));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did similar thing as u did in first example. but when function is calling itself recursively it still has 2 parameters. Second example might work, but i am not sure if i can use object as parameter.

Comment: second example DOES work (tested it) - and yes you **can** use an object as a parameter, I guess the question is, are you allowed to for the test

Comment: Yes that was the question. Thanks for help, i will try this, hope i will pass it.

Comment: But if you know how to do it with only passing and integer parameter to function just post here. Thanks again.